# Android and FCM, Maximal number of registered id's in one message?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

My answer is simple. What is the maximal number of registered id's I can send within one message in php by using FCM.

```
$fields = array
(
      'registration_ids'      => $registrationIds,
      'notification'          => $notif,
      'data'                  => $data
);
```

Other formulated: How many Id's can i push with

```
array_push($registrationIds,$id);
```

to registrationIds?

I found out that by around 500 id's the message was received by the last id, but by 1000 not. So is there a maximum or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From offical [FCM Http Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), it says

> **registration_ids :** It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.

So Maximum number is 1000.